# Fastest way to read a whole HDF5 containing Numpy arrays into memory

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I use :

```
import h5py

f = h5py.File('myfile.h5', 'r')
d = {}
for k in f.iterkeys():
    d[k] = f[k][:]
```

to read into memory the whole HDF5 file *(2 GB, 1000 `numpy` arrays of 2 MB each)*.

**Is there a faster way to load all the content of the HDF5 into memory ?**

(Maybe the loop here does a lot of "move" (seek?) in the file because each `f[k]` are not placed in the order that will give `for k in f.iterkeys()` ?)

Answer (score 8):

[PyTables](http://www.pytables.org) (another Python HDF5 Library) supports loading the whole file to memory using the [H5FD_CORE driver](http://pytables.github.io/cookbook/inmemory_hdf5_files.html). h5py would appear to support memory mapped files as well (see [File Drivers](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/file.html#file-drivers)). So just do

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File('myfile.h5', 'r', driver='core')
```

and you are done, as the file then already resides in memory.

Comment: Does memory-mapped files mean its loaded in memory?

Comment: @spurra Generally, no. But according to h5py’s documentation, all operations are done in memory.